# pattern of * no loops

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

So I have this code that does this:

```
.
..
...
...
..
.
```

But I want it to do:

```
.
..
...
..
.
```

I can't seem to find the bug that is adding the extra lines of dots.. If you have any suggestions that would be helpful fire away but keep in mind I'm trying to work without loops at this point in time... (currently studying for exam)

The code is:

```
public void put(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print(".");
        put(n-1);
    }
}

public void up(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        up(n - 1);
        put(n);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }   
}

public void down(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        put(n);
        System.out.print("\n");
        down(n-1);
    }
}

public void makePattern(int size) {
    stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    up(size);
    down(size);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger to step through your code to figure out where the code's execution diverges from what you expect.

Comment: up and down go to the same height.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to change is this method:

```
public void makePattern(int size) {
        stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        up(size);
        down(size);
    }
```

in `up` or `down` change `size` to `size-1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void put(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        System.out.print(".");
        put(n-1);
    }
}

public void up(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        up(n - 1);
        put(n);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public void down(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        put(n);
        System.out.print("\n");
        down(n-1);
    }
}

public void makePattern(int size) {
    stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    up(size);
    down(size-1);
}
```